# sqlalchemy add computed column as an instance of the object

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a statement in sqlalchemy as follows:

```
case_stmt = case((models.Evergreen.intended_remediation_date < models.Evergreen.obsolete_date,True),else_=False).label("obsolete_bool")
user = await db.execute(select(models.Evergreen,case_stmt).where(models.Evergreen.id == id))
users = user.all()
```

`db` is a session. I'm using sqlalchemy `2.0` . What I get returned is:

`[(<models.Evergreen object at 0x7f7800d339d0>, False)]`

What I would like to achieve is to be able to access a new attribute, say `users.obsolete_bool` which in this case has a value of `False` .

Essentially all I need is just to access the row objects as `row.obsolete_bool` but selecting the model class and one computed column returns the data above

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?  (current code is not a _reproduceable_ example, see: https://onlinegdb.com/ieh6BCcs4 )

Comment: My data is in the database but basically the same way one can access the row object attributes in this query `select(models.Evergreen.service_owner,models.Evergreen.software_product_version_name,models.Evergreen.id,case_stmt)` like `row.id` , how is it possible to access `Row` objects when selecting the whole model and an additional column

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to SQLAlchemy, so I started here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/engine.html

Now, five minutes later, I have this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/engine.html

engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/engine.html
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("CREATE TABLE some_table (x int, y int)"))
    conn.execute(
        text("INSERT INTO some_table (x, y) VALUES (:x, :y)"),
        [{"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 4}],
    )
    conn.commit()

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        text("INSERT INTO some_table (x, y) VALUES (:x, :y)"),
        [{"x": 6, "y": 8}, {"x": 9, "y": 10}],
    )

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT x, y FROM some_table"))
    for row in result:
        print(f"x: {row.x}  y: {row.y}")

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT x, y, x+y as z FROM some_table"))
    for row in result:
        print(f"x: {row.x}  y: {row.y}  z: {row.z}")
```

I think above shows how to get an extra column ( a computed column), which is not in the database?

Comment: that's nice but I don't see any ORM style there, just `CORE` . I'm using the session not the engine and I am selecting an ORM model , plus a case statement. It returns a tuple. The first object is an instance of Evergreen with all its attributes and the second is purely a boolean. Should i have selected the columns instead , like Evergreen.some_column I would have gotten a Row object, which i could iterate and get row.obsolete_bool. But I dont want to select the columns specifically, i want to select the ORM model and the case statement and be able to access the case statement by its attribute

Comment: Here is a lot of info of what i am trying to achieve, but could not figure out how to return Row
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#selecting-orm-entities-and-columns